# How does request meta work in python

Tags: scrapy, httprequest

In scrapy, if I make a request with large meta.
E.g.

`Request(url=url, meta=some_meta)`

Let's say that some_meta is some large dict. So, how does it affect request/response times, also if it is mapped to memory for reference than sending it to url endpoint, how is it done?. I'm newbie to scrapy, and I searched for this info, but could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

The meta option is for passing configuration settings to scrapy components on a per-request basis but doesn't necessarily directly map onto an http request.

There's a list of meta parameters accepted by the default extensions: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-meta

For instance if you pass `meta={'dont_retry': True}` the request won't be retried if it fails. Different options have different impact on request/response times. Not retrying would of course make faulty urls give up the response faster.

Comment: What if I have to access item dict, e.g. Request(url=url, meta=item_dict). And that dict is very large object. Does it affect request/response times?

Comment: @pnv As a practical matter not really. You would have to do something quite spectacular to to affect a modern computer. Your settings and the speed of light is what's going to limit the request/response time more than anything else when you're sending requests over the internet.